# RE : setting value to age but getting errors with null on other keys

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I am working on a script (setage) which automatically sets the age from dob date in my table.

this is my table (mytable) desc :

```
ID, NOT NULL, varchar(20)
DOB, DATE
AGE, int


insert into MYTABLE(AGE)
SELECT TRUNC(MONTHS_BETWEEN(SYSDATE,DOB)/12)
FROM MYTABLE;
```

But I am receiving an  error of

```
cannot insert NULL into ("my-PC"."MYTABLE"."ID")
```

I am sure that I several records inside my table with ID and DOB inputs, but not my age.
But why is the system saying I could not inside due to my ID field ?

Answer (score 1):

Check your datatypes.

- You have **varchar** in ID.
- TRUNC() is for **date**.
- Whereas MONTH_BETWEEN() returns **floating point**